# Combining if-then statements

Tags: java, if-statement, integer

I'm trying to convert individual integers to from their ASCII values to 0s and 1s. The relevant code looks something like this:

```
    int num1 = bin.charAt(0);
    int num2 = bin.charAt(1);
    int num3 = bin.charAt(2);
    int num4 = bin.charAt(3);

    if (num1 == 49) 
    {
        num1 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        num1 = 0;
    }

    if (num2 == 49) 
    {num2 = 1;}
    else
    {
        num2 = 0;
    }
```

Is there a way to combine if/else statements so that I don't have 30 lines of code of the same principle?

I tried
           `if (num1 == 49 || num2 ==49`)
but I'm not sure how to only assign the value that is equal to 49 to 0.

Comment: Look into boolean operators `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Also look into the ternary operator, e.g. `num1 = (num1 == 49) ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: If you are performing the same action a lot of times, you probably want to create a method for it.

Comment: How on earth `chatAt(0)` will be `49` ?

Comment: Save your ints in an array then loop through them applying the if statement to each index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `bin` array to another `num` array of `int`s.

```
int[] num = new int[bin.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
    char c = bin[i];
    num[i] = Character.digit(c, 10);
}
```

That will map any `char` digit to an `int` digit. If you strictly want to convert only `char` "1" to `int` 1 and any other `char` to `int` 0, you can implement it as

```
num[i] = (c == 49) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: `Character.digit(c, 10)` is more meaningful than `c - 48`.

Comment: @AndyTurner - you are right, thanks! I corrected the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to just use some functions that already exist:

```
String string = Integer.decode(bin).toBinaryString();
```

Comment: `Integer.decode(bin)` might be easier than `new Integer(Integer.parseInt(bin))`.